# MYSQL : How do I get the maximum of a quantity sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT p.pub_name, t.title, YEAR(s.ord_date) AS YEAR, SUM(s.qty) AS "QTY SUM"
FROM publishers p JOIN titles t ON p.pub_id = t.pub_id
                  JOIN sales s ON t.title_id = s.title_id
GROUP BY p.pub_name, t.title, YEAR(s.ord_date);
```

and the results for the query here:

[image: query results]

How do I show only the highest `QTY SUM` per `pub_name`?

Something like the attached photo below, showing only the highlighted rows...

[image: desired results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT pty.*
FROM (SELECT p.pub_name, t.title, YEAR(s.ord_date) AS YEAR, SUM(s.qty) AS sum_qty,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.pub_name ORDER BY SUM(s.qty) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM publishers p JOIN
           titles t
           ON p.pub_id = t.pub_id JOIN
           sales s
           ON t.title_id = s.title_id
      GROUP BY p.pub_name, t.title, YEAR(s.ord_date)
     ) pty
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Am I missing something, why wouldn't a simple ORDER BY be enough? In my quick test that seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Martijn . . . The question is asking:  "How do I show only the highest `QTY SUM` per `pub_name`?"